# MyFonts not loading in IE11

Tags: fonts

I am using myfonts.com and I am having trouble with the fonts loading on my website in IE. It works in all other browsers except IE. I know the font was working in IE before so not sure what happened. I updated my .conf file to include:

```
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject  eot
    AddType application/x-font-ttf         ttf ttc
    AddType font/opentype                  otf
    AddType application/x-font-woff        woff

    <FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot)$">
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
            Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
        </IfModule>
    </FilesMatch>
```

But it is not fix anything in IE. I am using a Drupal module to aggregate the css and js files but I have had this activated for a while.

The current aggregated css files that has all the font code is here: http://www.conversantmedia.com/sites/default/files/advagg_css/css__PdX-jPfNonX3vr6Xsf6J8txZplbenPiwShyRVNfiiGY__gA9jiO1xM4UrdGqDeMnU5Z8CvzThLTXtrWvy7CN5qK0__bCRKGeMGFZs62JGMB8rSVUheJ9__mLTZclIEugiyhyw.css

The website is here: http://www.conversantmedia.com/

Would anyone have any advice? In IE I do not see any major errors just warnings but would that prevent the font from loading?

Comment: So I am using a RDC, but I just ran another test using codepen cross browser testing and the font loads, so I guess it may not be an issue, maybe my RDC is just weird overall.

Comment: protip: it's 2016, the only format you need for modern, supporte browsers, is WOFF. Don't use eot unless you need to support IE8 and below (which MS no longer supports), don't use ttf/otf because WOFF is the byte-for-byte equivalent but then explicitly marked as "for web use" instead. And CSS does not support font collections, period, so ttc never made sense to begin with =)